# Making Current To Flow In One Direction

Tags: current

Consider This Circuit:

[image: Circuit]

As you can see we have 3 switches and thus three routes to the output, we can control each switch, but **only one switch can be closed at any moment** .

We do not have any problem with switching part of the circuit (and in fact we can't simply change it).

Our problem with this circuit, if we close the third switch, current will flow in the circuit like this:

[image: Currents]

we just don't want the current to flow in the second rout (or R1 - Red route), or if we close the second switch we don't want the current to flow in the third route (Or R3) , I think you've got the whole idea, we want our routs lead the current in just one direction, the most simple solution is using series diode on the routes that can cause a voltage drop and we don't want it .

So what do you suggest? I have to mention that output is going to be connected to ADC input, so we just want to prevent any kind of voltage or current drops as far as possible. And if a drop is inevitable, we want it to be constant or somehow computable, so we can set a bias.

Comment: You should add your goals and constraints - the obvious answer is to move the switches, or use dual-gang ones. If you can change the topology, then something like http://www.reuk.co.uk/wordpress/multiple-buttonsswitches-on-one-adc-input/ might meet your needs

Comment: Thanks man, but i think you got me wrong i cant change the switching part of circuit, in fact switching system is way more complicated than what I've shown in the circuit above and its sort of impossible to change it, i just want to find a way to just isolate the routs ,like by adding a diode but in a more efficient way. @PeteKirkham

Comment: Any constraints on the voltages at the left side of the switches?

Comment: First Switch is for signals with Voltage amplitude between 0 to 2 v , second one is for signals with current amplitude between 0 - 10 ma (for this signals current is important to us so we cross it though a resistor and we read the voltage) , and the the third switch is for signals with Voltage amplitude between 4 to 10 v and cross though a Voltage divider to scale the amplitude between 2 - 5 v . by the way i must mention that again :only one switch can be closed at any moment. @Chu

Comment: Start by placing a diode somewhere along the green path and see what happens.

Comment: @Chu, what do you think will happen? OP explained that diodes will cause voltage drop which is unacceptable.

Comment: @transistor, precision rectifier would remove voltage drop.

Comment: A precision rectifier is a lot more that the diode suggested in your comment. And how would you feed the three precision rectifiers into the ADC?

Comment: @transistor, a precision rectifier is a perfect diode. I don't see any such restrictions in the question. Plus, the question says that voltage drops are not desirable, but can be tolerated as long as they're computable. The voltage drop across a normal diode is computable. My post is intended to encourage the OP to think about a solution rather than give it on a plate. – Chu 1 hour ago

Answer (score 1):

If you are connecting the signals to a analog digital converter, the solution is to use a multiplexer, for example [4051](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/MC14051B-D.PDF) to switch safely, with minimal influence on other channels.
Of course, using a multiplexer, slightly increases the complexity of your circuit. The control circuit is not described in your question.
Anyway, R1, R2 and R3 resistances should be on the other side of switches.

Comment: Thanks Bro! , but switching system is way more complicated than what I've shown in the circuit above and its sort of impossible to change it , and we also cant change the placement of resistors , we just looking for a way to just isolate the routs ,like by adding a diode but in a more efficient way.

Comment: @Sepehr Maybe a Precision Rectifier? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_rectifier

Comment: It seems Intriguing to me , I should give it a try, but it dosent seem to fit this problem. @Martin Petrei

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJL5DZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Just sum the three inputs. An open switch will contribute nothing to the output.

A starting set of values would be R14 to R19 being the same.

Notice that VGnd is 0V. So you can choose R11 such that R11 || R15 to be your original R1's value. Similarly for R13.

You do need a negative supply for this schematic as given.

Answer (score 0):

what do you think about using dpst switch?
no voltage or current drop, no extra components.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To make any sense of the signals coming to it the ADC or whatever is using the ADC digital value will need to know which switch is on. If it knows which switch is on then you can use the same signal to multiplex the inputs to the ADC.

This could be done using external multiplexers or, for example, an 8-channel ADC which, typically, has an internal multiplexer with three pins to select which analog input to read.